# Magento2 Enterprise Gift Card Orders

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise

We have Magento 2.3.4 Enterprise Cloud and wanting to use the default Gift Card functionality . Our issue seems to be that when someone places an order for a gift card enters their credit card. however the order seems to stay as processing and I seem to have to manually go into the Magento admin panel and go to the invoice and click capture online. Not sure if there is a setting I need to click in the admin panel that I am missing?

These are for orders that contain only the gift card so should just complete instantly as no shipping is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change payment action from authorize to sale (auth and capture) for your payment method in store configuration.